# Include directory of jars into bundle with bnd

Tags: gradle, bnd

I am able to successfully build a bundle with the bnd gradle plugin that includes a dependency jar, using `-includeresource`. However, when I try to build the directory of jar(s) to include programmatically, and try to include this entire directory into the bundle, like this:

```
jar {
    dependsOn copyJars
    // Build OSGI bundle, including the incompatible version of the transitive dependency
    bnd('-exportcontents': 'com.example.foo',
            '-sources': 'false',
            '-includeresource': 'build/tmp/include/=lib/; lib:=true')
}
```

the `copyJars` task works (I can see the jar file has been copied), but then I get this error:

```
error  : Input file does not exist: lib/
error  : Input file does not exist: lib/
```

which does not make sense - `lib/` is not an input, it's an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it *was* given as an input file - it's the wrong way round. It should be:

```
'-includeresource': 'lib/=build/tmp/include/; lib:=true')
```